# C# - Unity3D trouble with GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag and foreach

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

First I find the objects that interest me using `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag`. And I bring them into one array All[ ] . I create `NavMeshAgent`>. I drive the agent to selected points on the map. Until he meets someone from the All[ ] array. And it would seem that everything works, but BUT. The agent only triggers on the last object in the array. I sat for 2 days, tried many ways, the result is the same, it can run the array not through ( foreach or for ) . Maybe there is a complex solution to the problem. Or even another way, I'm in the programming of bread, but I try my best. Any idea is accepted and tested. Thanks!!!

`public void getTarget(GameObject[] targets)` runs through array objects - this is where the problem lies

`public GameObject[] Concat(GameObject[] first, GameObject[] second, GameObject[] third)` concatenates arrays of objects

`public void moveToTarget(Vector3 target)` points to the target for the

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class MinionMoveByLine : MonoBehaviour
{
public enum MovementType
{
    Moveing,
    Learp
}
//Переменные для перемещения по карте
public MovementType type = MovementType.Moveing;
public NavMeshLineToMove MyLine;
public float speed = 1;
public float maxDistance = .3f;
private NavMeshAgent enemy;

//Переменные для растояний и приоритета крипов
private GameObject[] minions;
private GameObject[] towers;
private GameObject[] players;
private GameObject[] All;
public GameObject minion;
private Vector3[] position;
private Vector3 targetPosition;
private float distanceVisionForAttack = 6f; 
private float radiusOfAttack = 2f;

private IEnumerator<Transform> pointInPath;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
    minions = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("minion");
    towers =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tower");
    players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("player");

    All = Concat(players, towers, minions);        
    Debug.Log("minions "+ minions.Length);
    Debug.Log("towers " + towers.Length);
    Debug.Log("players " + players.Length);

    minion = (GameObject)this.gameObject;

    enemy = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    
    if (MyLine == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Line Not Set");
        return;       
    }

    pointInPath = MyLine.GetNextPathPoint();

    pointInPath.MoveNext();

    if (pointInPath.Current == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Need point to move");
        return;
    }

    transform.position = pointInPath.Current.position;

}

void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 position = minion.transform.position;

    if (pointInPath == null || pointInPath.Current == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach(var obj in All)
    {
        Debug.Log(All.Length);
        Debug.Log(obj);
    }
    getTarget(All);
           
     var distanceSqure = (transform.position - pointInPath.Current.position).sqrMagnitude;
    if (distanceSqure < maxDistance * maxDistance)
    {
        pointInPath.MoveNext();
    }
   
}

public GameObject[] Concat(GameObject[] first, GameObject[] second, GameObject[] third)
{
    GameObject[] Concated = new GameObject[first.Length+second.Length+third.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
    {
        Concated[i] = first[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < second.Length; i++)
    {
        Concated[first.Length + i] = second[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < third.Length; i++)
    {
        Concated[first.Length + second.Length + i] = third[i];
    }
    return Concated;
}

public void getTarget(GameObject[] targets)
{
    
    Vector3 minionPosition = this.transform.position;
    
    foreach (GameObject go in targets)
    {
        
        Transform transform = go.GetComponent<Transform>();
        Vector3 transformPosition = transform.position;
        float distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(transformPosition, minionPosition);
        if (distanceToTarget <= distanceVisionForAttack && distanceToTarget > radiusOfAttack)
        {
            moveToTarget(transformPosition);
        }else if(distanceToTarget <= radiusOfAttack)
        {
            moveToTarget(minion.transform.position);
        }
        else if(type == MovementType.Moveing && distanceToTarget > distanceVisionForAttack)
            {

            enemy.SetDestination(pointInPath.Current.position);
        }
    }
    

    var distanceSqure = (transform.position - pointInPath.Current.position).sqrMagnitude;
    if (distanceSqure < maxDistance * maxDistance)
    {
        pointInPath.MoveNext();
    }
}

public void moveToTarget(Vector3 target)
{
    enemy.SetDestination(target);
    
}
```

}

[result of starting scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgDDd.png)

[What is happening in redactor - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9KNzJJEMcg)

Comment: Why do you pass the All array when it’s a class variable and you can just use it? Enemy and minion seem to be the same gameobject?

Comment: @BugFinder 
no, enemy and minion are different objects with different tags and functionality. can I ask you to send a link to the documentation on how to use a class variable, otherwise I don’t fully understand what you are talking about

Comment: Well in your start code minion is set to the current gameobject. Enemy the navmesh on this same game object. You dont need to declare minion gameObject will already refer to this. 

And you managed to use class variables in other methods. So you you already have that information on how to use the All and not need to pass it

Comment: @BugFinder 
yes, the current code determines everything correctly, but changes the target direction only when it is within the radius of the last object in the All array. and no matter how I change this code, sorting through each array that is bound by the tag search, or combining everything into one, only the last object to which the distance is checked changes the target direction of the minion (of this code)

Comment: @BugFinder 
if you watched the video, then just the same object that the minion followed is the last one in the array, and the idea was to implement the same behavior for everyone on its path, but it does not react to them in any way

Comment: It doesn’t help you declare a variable called transform of the potential target game object. When transform also would refer to the transform of the gameobject you’re on. 

You seem to make a lot of variables that make reading this so much harder. But in short. 


Yes. It will always do the last one because you set the same thing for each target  it will do it for all of them and the last one is always last. If you only mean to do the nearest. You need a loop to work out which is the nearest and  then do only that.  If you did x=1;x=3;x=5 x will always be 5. This is what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I leave for those who in the future will face the same stupidity as me, change

```
 getTarget ( );
```

new variables added

```
GameObject currentTarget;
float dist = Mathf.Infinity;
```

and cycle

```
foreach(GameObject go in targets)
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = go.transform.position;
        float distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(targetPosition, 
minionPosition);
        if (distanceToTarget < dist)
        {
            dist = distanceToTarget;
            currentTarget = go;
        }
    }
```

Special thanks to BugFinder

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class MinionMoveByLine : MonoBehaviour
{
public enum MovementType
{
    Moveing,
    Learp
}
//Переменные для перемещения по карте
public MovementType type = MovementType.Moveing;
public NavMeshLineToMove MyLine;
public float speed = 1;
public float maxDistance = .3f;
private NavMeshAgent enemy;

//Переменные для растояний и приоритета крипов
private GameObject[] minions;
private GameObject[] towers;
private GameObject[] players;
private GameObject[] All;
public GameObject minion;
private Vector3[] position;
private Vector3 targetPosition;
private float distanceVisionForAttack = 6f; 
private float radiusOfAttack = 2f;
GameObject currentTarget;
float dist = Mathf.Infinity;
private IEnumerator<Transform> pointInPath;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
    minions = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("minion");
    towers =  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tower");
    players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("player");

    All = Concat(players, towers, minions);        
    Debug.Log("minions "+ minions.Length);
    Debug.Log("towers " + towers.Length);
    Debug.Log("players " + players.Length);
    //currentTarget = All[0];
    minion = (GameObject)this.gameObject;

    enemy = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    
    if (MyLine == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Line Not Set");
        return;       
    }

    pointInPath = MyLine.GetNextPathPoint();

    pointInPath.MoveNext();

    if (pointInPath.Current == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Need point to move");
        return;
    }

    transform.position = pointInPath.Current.position;

}

void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 position = minion.transform.position;

    if (pointInPath == null || pointInPath.Current == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    foreach(var obj in All)
    {
        Debug.Log(All.Length);
        Debug.Log(obj);
    }
    getTarget(All);
           
     var distanceSqure = (transform.position - pointInPath.Current.position).sqrMagnitude;
    if (distanceSqure < maxDistance * maxDistance)
    {
        pointInPath.MoveNext();
    }
   
}

public GameObject[] Concat(GameObject[] first, GameObject[] second, GameObject[] third)
{
    GameObject[] Concated = new GameObject[first.Length+second.Length+third.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
    {
        Concated[i] = first[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < second.Length; i++)
    {
        Concated[first.Length + i] = second[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < third.Length; i++)
    {
        Concated[first.Length + second.Length + i] = third[i];
    }
    return Concated;
}

public void getTarget(GameObject[] targets)
{
    
    

    Vector3 minionPosition = this.transform.position;
    
    foreach (GameObject go in targets)
    {          
        Vector3 targetPosition = go.transform.position;
        float distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(targetPosition, minionPosition);
        if (distanceToTarget < dist)
        {
            dist = distanceToTarget;
            currentTarget = go;
        }
       
    }
    float distanceToCurrentTarget = Vector3.Distance(currentTarget.transform.position, minionPosition);
    if (distanceToCurrentTarget <= distanceVisionForAttack && distanceToCurrentTarget > radiusOfAttack)
    {
        moveToTarget(currentTarget);
    }
    else if (distanceToCurrentTarget <= radiusOfAttack)
    {
        moveToTarget(minion);
    }
    else if (type == MovementType.Moveing && distanceToCurrentTarget > distanceVisionForAttack)
    {
        dist = Mathf.Infinity;
        enemy.SetDestination(pointInPath.Current.position);
    }

    var distanceSqure = (transform.position - pointInPath.Current.position).sqrMagnitude;
    if (distanceSqure < maxDistance * maxDistance)
    {
        pointInPath.MoveNext();
    }
}

public void moveToTarget(GameObject target)
 {
    enemy.SetDestination(target.transform.position);
    
 }
}
```